# Python3.4 'str' doens not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and have googled ALOT on this problem and I don't get it to work. 
I'm trying to write a value from Roborealm to Python and everything work except that i don't get it to write the value, because of the problem that it doesn't support str.

Here is my own code, the rest of my code is from Roborealm:

```
rr = RR_API()
width = 0
height = 0
rr.Connect("localhost")
import math 
import socket
Clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Clientsocket.bind(("localhost", 4040))
serversocket = Clientsocket



#Circles
Circles = str(rr.GetVariable("CirclesCount"), "utf-8")
if Circles >=1:
  print ("Circles = "+rr.GetVariable("CIRCLES_COUNT"))
```

And the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RU21\Desktop\Röda puckar\Förbindelse med RR.py", line 281, in <module>
    Circles = str(rr.GetVariable("CirclesCount"), "utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\RU21\Desktop\Röda puckar\Förbindelse med RR.py", line 117, in GetVariable
    self.sock.send("<request><get_variable>"+str(name) +"</get_variable></request>")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I'm new to Python and I have googled ALOT and this is my last chance of getting it to work so please help me.

Comment: You need a *bytes* value, not a string. But you **already have a string**.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `C:\Users\RU21\Desktop\Röda puckar\Förbindelse med RR.py`, not (only) in your code.

Looking at the traceback, it seems that Roborealm does not support Python 3.x. You should install Python 2.7 and try agin.

Comment: Ah, right. I did not read the traceback correctly.

Comment: THANKS ALOT, installed Python 2.7 and my code worked :)

Answer (score 0):

`rr.GetVariable("CirclesCount")` is returning a str object. You would only need to specify the `"utf-8"` encoding argument if you had encoded bytes, but since you getting a decoded str, all you need to do is:

```
Circles = str(rr.GetVariable("CirclesCount"))
```

or just (which is better):

```
Circles = rr.GetVariable("CirclesCount")
```

Here is the relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str

Comment: I've tried both ways you said but i still get the same error code. I've tried delete 'str' in Roborealms code also but then i get the error. TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: don't call `str()`; unless it is necessary.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes. I included the str() version to highlight the 2 str signatures. I've edited my answer indicate that without the str call is better.